# MongoDb deleteOne not returning writeConcern?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, database

I have a method to delete a specific document in MongoDb based on an id match. The code is provided below.

```
deletePoll: function(db, user_id, callback) {
        db.collection('polls').deleteOne({
                _id: user_id
            },
            function(err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
                if(result){
                    console.log(result);
                }
            });
    }
```

Now, the above code only returns a massive object on the if(result) being passed. The result object it logs is provided below.

```
{ result: { ok: 1, n: 0 },
  connection: 
   EventEmitter {
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { error: [Object],
        close: [Object],
        timeout: [Object],
        parseError: [Object] },
     _eventsCount: 4,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     options: 
      { host: 'localhost',
        port: 27017,
        size: 5,
        connectionTimeout: 30000,
        socketTimeout: 30000,
        keepAlive: true,
        keepAliveInitialDelay: 0,
        noDelay: true,
        ssl: false,
        checkServerIdentity: true,
        ca: null,
        cert: null,
        key: null,
        passPhrase: null,
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
        promoteLongs: true,
        promoteValues: true,
        promoteBuffers: false,
        reconnect: true,
        reconnectInterval: 1000,
        reconnectTries: 30,
        domainsEnabled: false,
        disconnectHandler: [Object],
        cursorFactory: [Object],
        emitError: true,
        socketOptions: {},
        clientInfo: [Object],
        readPreference: [Object],
        promiseLibrary: [Function: Promise],
        bson: {} },
     id: 0,
     logger: { className: 'Connection' },
     bson: {},
     tag: undefined,
     messageHandler: [Function],
     maxBsonMessageSize: 67108864,
     port: 27017,
     host: 'localhost',
     keepAlive: true,
     keepAliveInitialDelay: 0,
     noDelay: true,
     connectionTimeout: 30000,
     socketTimeout: 30000,
     destroyed: false,
     domainSocket: false,
     singleBufferSerializtion: true,
     serializationFunction: 'toBinUnified',
     ca: null,
     cert: null,
     key: null,
     passphrase: null,
     ssl: false,
     rejectUnauthorized: false,
     checkServerIdentity: true,
     responseOptions: 
      { promoteLongs: true,
        promoteValues: true,
        promoteBuffers: false },
     flushing: false,
     queue: [],
     connection: 
      Socket {
        _connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: [Object],
        _parent: null,
        _host: 'localhost',
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: true,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 8,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: true,
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        destroyed: false,
        _bytesDispatched: 8218,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: null,
        _server: null,
        _idleTimeout: 30000,
        _idleNext: [Object],
        _idlePrev: [Object],
        _idleStart: 143353,
        read: [Function],
        _consuming: true },
     writeStream: null,
     hashedName: '29bafad3b32b11dc7ce934204952515ea5984b3c',
     workItem: null,
     buffer: null,
     sizeOfMessage: 0,
     bytesRead: 0,
     stubBuffer: null },
  message: 
   { parsed: true,
     index: 56,
     raw: <Buffer 38 00 00 00 36 00 00 00 23 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 14 00 00 00 10 6f 6b 00 01 00 00 00 10 6e ... >,
     data: <Buffer 38 00 00 00 36 00 00 00 23 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 14 00 00 00 10 6f 6b 00 01 00 00 00 10 6e ... >,
     bson: {},
     opts: 
      { promoteLongs: true,
        promoteValues: true,
        promoteBuffers: false },
     length: 56,
     requestId: 54,
     responseTo: 35,
     responseFlags: 8,
     cursorId: Long { _bsontype: 'Long', low_: 0, high_: 0 },
     startingFrom: 0,
     numberReturned: 1,
     documents: [ [Object] ],
     cursorNotFound: false,
     queryFailure: false,
     shardConfigStale: false,
     awaitCapable: true,
     promoteLongs: true,
     promoteValues: true,
     promoteBuffers: false,
     hashedName: '29bafad3b32b11dc7ce934204952515ea5984b3c' },
  deletedCount: 0 }
```

And when I check the mongo console manually, the document is not deleted. What am I doing wrong here? Why is the document not being deleted? And why is the writeConcern object not returning? Why am I getting this massive object returned instead?

Comment: What version of mongo are you using and what version of the mongodb node driver are you using (I'm assuming you are doing this in node since you tagger the question as javascript). Versions 2.x of the node mongodb driver have the `deleteOne`. Versions 1.x do not have deleteOne.

Comment: My package.json file lists the mongodb dependency as version "mongodb": "^2.2.9"
How do I figure out what version of mongo I am using?

Comment: [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/driver-compatibility-reference/#node-js-driver-compatibility) will show you what version of driver you can use with what version of mongodb. To check the version of mongodb that you have running, inside your shell, you can call `db.version()`. If you are working locally, then your shell and mondod will have the same version, and your shell tells you its version when you first log in.

Comment: Hey check out my updated answer to your question. I think your issue is related to the `_id` part of your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think you're issue might be the `user_id`. What are you passing in to that parameter? Is it a String? If so, you probably need to have `{ _id: new ObjectId(user_id) }` as the first argument in the deleteOne function. If you look at the bottom of the output you're getting, it says `deletedCount: 0`. It's probably trying to match the string `user_id` to the `_id` of some document, which is of type `ObjectID`. So since you're comparing a string to an `ObjectId`, it seems that you won't ever have a match. [Documentation for ObjectId](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/ObjectID.html). I'm pretty sure this is the problem. I've had similar problems before. If this doesn't fix it, you can try the suggestions below.

Also, [check this out](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#deleteOne) it seems you should be passing in filter object, an options object, and then your callback. It seems you are missing the options object. You might try passing in `null` or `{}` as your second parameter before your callback.

Although based on the [documentation for db](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Db.html#collection), it seems your issue may be a timing issue. `db.collection('colName')` also expects a call back if you put it in strict mode. So you could try the following:

```
deletePoll: function(db, user_id, callback) {
        db.collection('polls', { strict: true }, function (err, col) {
            if (err) {
              // handle error
            } else {
              deleteUser(col);
            }
        });    
    }

function deleteUser(col) {
    col.deleteOne({
        _id: user_id
    },
    function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hey, my issue was my user_id was a string and I needed it to use new ObjectId(user_id) like you said. Thanks for your help!